# Most comfortable way to use the unicode font "Mathematical Bold Fraktur" on Windows

Tags: windows-10, fonts, unicode

I would like to know if there is a way to write in "Mathematical Bold Fraktur" in my browser or better system wide (Windows 10). It also would be very nice if there is a way to use this font in Photoshop. Currently the only way to use this font, is to go to a unicode text converter website and copy/paste from there. But that's too complicated for me. Any ideas?